# In ReactJS is component state tied to an instance of the component or is it tied to all instances of the component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am trying to display multiple instances of a component on a page. Each instance should appear within a Tab.Pane (Semantic UI feature). However in my attempt to achieve this, I am getting some strange behaviour as explained in more detail below.

I have a component; `<MultistepFilterSection />`

Within this component the state is:

```
this.state = {
    conjunction: "AND" // default
}
```

This state is modified by a onClick handler function in the component;

```
handleConjunctionButtonClick = (conjunction, e) => {
    this.setState({conjunction: conjunction})
}
```

This onClick is triggered by clicking on one of two buttons:

```
<Button.Group vertical>
    <Button 
        onClick={(e) => this.handleConjunctionButtonClick("AND")}
        color={this.state.conjunction === "AND" ? "blue" : null}
    >   
        And
    </Button>
    <Button
        onClick={(e) => this.handleConjunctionButtonClick("OR")}
        color={this.state.conjunction === "OR" ? "blue" : null}
    >
        Or
    </Button>
</Button.Group>
```

I am using [Semantic UI's Tab component](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/tab/) to render  3 instances of this component on a page;

```
    const panes = [
        { 
            menuItem: "Panel Data", 
            render: () => 
                <Tab.Pane attached={false}>
                    <MultistepFilterSection getAudience={this.getAudience} />
                </Tab.Pane>
        },
        { 
            menuItem: "Geolocation Data", 
            render: () => 
                <Tab.Pane attached={false}>
                    <MultistepFilterSection getAudience={this.getAudience} />
                </Tab.Pane>
        },
        { 
            menuItem: "Combined Audience Selection", 
            render: () => 
                <Tab.Pane attached={false}>
                    <MultistepFilterSection getAudience={this.getAudience} />
                </Tab.Pane>
        }
    ]
```

In the render method I have:

```
                <Tab 
                    menu={{ secondary: true, pointing: true }} 
                    panes={panes} 
                />
```

Triggering the onClick handler in any one of the tabs changes the state in all instances of the component. Is this normal? I thought that the component state in one instance of the component is exclusive to that instance.

On further investigation, I found that the behaviour is exhibited when I'm instantiating multiple instances of the `<MultistepFilterSection />` using Semantic UI's Tab component. When rendering the instances on their own, the exhibit expected behaviour.

The full code of the `<MultistepFilterSection />` component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Grid, Button, Container, Icon, Segment } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import uuid from "uuid";
import _ from "lodash";

import RuleGroup from "../rules/RuleGroup";
import { filterGroupCreated, filterGroupDeleted, filterDeleted } from "../../actions/FiltersAction"

export class MultistepFilterSection extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            conjunction: "AND" // default
        }

        // create one default group
        this.props.filterGroupCreated({filterGroupId: uuid()})

        this.handleAddRuleGroupButtonClick = this.handleAddRuleGroupButtonClick.bind(this);
        this.renderRuleGroups = this.renderRuleGroups.bind(this);
        this.handleConjunctionButtonClick.bind(this)
    }

    handleAddRuleGroupButtonClick() {
        // console.log("called handleAddRuleGroupButtonClick()")
        const filterGroupId = uuid()
        let data = {}
        data.filterGroupId = filterGroupId

        this.props.filterGroupCreated(data)
    }

    handleConjunctionButtonClick = (conjunction, e) => {
        this.setState({conjunction: conjunction})
    }

    renderRuleGroups() {
        // console.log("called renderRuleGroups()")
        return Object.values(this.props.filterGroups).map(function(ruleGroup) {
            const key = ruleGroup.id;

            // incomplete
            let currentGenderSelected

            return (
                <React.Fragment key={key}>
                    <RuleGroup
                        id={key} 
                        key={key} 
                        deleteRuleGroup={this.deleteRuleGroup}
                        deleteFilter={this.deleteFilter}
                        currentGenderSelected={currentGenderSelected}
                    />
                </React.Fragment>

            )
        }.bind(this))
    }

    deleteRuleGroup = (id, e) => {
        // console.log("delete rule group called")

        this.props.filterGroupDeleted({filterGroupId: id})
    }

    deleteFilter = (filterGroupId, filterId, e) => {
        // console.log("deleteFilter() called")

        this.props.filterDeleted({
            filterGroupId: filterGroupId, 
            filterId: filterId
        })
    }

    render() {
        const isFilterGroupQuery = true
        return(
            <Grid  padded="vertically">
                <Grid.Row stretched>
                    <Grid.Column  verticalAlign={"middle"} width={2}>
                        {_.size(this.props.filterGroups) > 0 &&
                            <Segment basic>
                                <Button.Group vertical>
                                    <Button 
                                        onClick={(e) => this.handleConjunctionButtonClick("AND")}
                                        color={this.state.conjunction === "AND" ? "blue" : null}
                                    >   
                                        And
                                    </Button>
                                    <Button
                                        onClick={(e) => this.handleConjunctionButtonClick("OR")}
                                        color={this.state.conjunction === "OR" ? "blue" : null}
                                    >
                                        Or
                                    </Button>
                                </Button.Group>
                            </Segment>
                        }
                    </Grid.Column>
                    <Grid.Column width={14}>
                        {this.renderRuleGroups()}
                    </Grid.Column>
                </Grid.Row>
                <Grid.Row>
                    <Grid.Column width={2}></Grid.Column>
                    <Grid.Column width={3}>
                        <Button
                            color="grey" 
                            basic 
                            onClick={this.handleAddRuleGroupButtonClick}
                        >
                            <Icon name="plus" />Add Rule Group
                        </Button>
                    </Grid.Column>
                    <Grid.Column width={11}>
                        <Button 
                            color="blue"
                            onClick={
                                (isFilterGroupQuery) => this.props.getAudience(
                                    isFilterGroupQuery, this.state.conjunction
                                )
                            }
                            floated={"right"} 
                        >
                            Run query
                        </Button>
                    </Grid.Column>

                </Grid.Row>
            </Grid>

        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        filterGroups: state.filters
    };
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps, 
    {
        filterGroupCreated,
        filterGroupDeleted,
        filterDeleted
    }
)(MultistepFilterSection);
```

Comment: It is definitely not normal, `state` is for a component instance and is not supposed to be shared. You should probably share more of your code if you need further help.

Comment: You need to store and manage state within the parent component housing MultistepFilterSection.  From there you pass the button click function into each component.  Idea being that if any MultistepFilterSection components on click is called, then the state is only update in the parent component.  You ought to look at the React docs as they are excellent. The following link describes exactly what you want to do.  https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: this is not normal, the state should be updated only for the component which is clicked, please share your code, will help us to suggest a fix.

Comment: Where are you linking the onClick handler handleConjunctionButtonClick () , please provide that code.

Comment: Share the complete code of MultiStepFilterSection component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much digging around and eventually [posting an issue](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/3475) on Semantic UI's GitHub repo, I learned that I needed to use `renderActiveOnly={false}` prop on the Tab component. I also had to change my markup so that panes objects were in the following format:

```
  const panes = [
        { 
            key: 1,
            menuItem: "Panel Data", 
            pane: <Tab.Pane><Simple key={1} /></Tab.Pane>
        },
        { 
            key: 2,
            menuItem: "Geolocation Data", 
            pane: <Tab.Pane><Simple key={2} /></Tab.Pane>
        }
    ]
```